# Create points from line endpoints in Arcmap

Tags: gis, arcgis, esri

Arc 10.6.1

This seems like it should be simple, but only tools found don't seem to do quite what I'm looking for.

I have a line layer of Forest Service Trails and I want to use it to create a new layer of trailheads (I have not been able to find standalone trailhead data, so I'm trying to proxy).

I plan to dissolve the line features based on name so individual trails are contiguous, but then I want to create points from the ends of each of these features. Is there a tool to create points from line beginings/ends?

Answer (score 0):

See this support doco https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012326

Essentially add x,y coordinates for the start end of each line to your line feature class using the  Add Geometry Attributes.

Once you have the x,y coordinates you can generate new point layers for the start and another for the ends using the  Make XY Event Layer tool.  If needed you can merge them all into the one layer.

Comment: Thanks! As I kept digging I started to suspect it would be this kind of workaround. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need an advanced license, but why not use the tool Feature Vertices to Points?  You can specify to generate both end and start.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The feature Vertices to Points tool works best for me. It has several options or ways to export the file. You can choose between

1. Start Vertex
2. End Vertex
3. Both Start and End Vertex
4. Mid point